# Audio-element in HTML code but not visible

Tags: angularjs, html, audio, html5-audio

When I add the audio-tag in the sourcecode/html, it will not be visible in the browser.

[When I manually add the html in an existing HTML-page, the audio-element will not be shown. When I add some text with for example the strong-element, it will appear as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlUbQ.jpg)

In my case I used Angular.js to add the audio-elements after loading data dynamically. The  is in the sourcecode according to the element inspector from Chrome/Firefox, but the [audio-element is not be visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mw3U7.jpg).

The audio-element will be visible when loading it in a static page.

Is it possible to add the audio/video-element dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe if you puts controls="control" in the audio tag you will see the controls